# Manipulating large set of CSV data in memory

Tags: c#, performance, datatable

I am trying to manipulate a large set(10 million record) of data that I have imported into a datatable. I don't think the datatable is the most efficient way of manipulating a large set of data in memory. Does anyone have a better way of doing this? What I am trying to do is taking the contents of a CSV file manipulate some of the data and re-export the results into another CSV file.

TIA,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataTable` will require loading the whole thing into memory at once. Don't do that. Instead treat both the in and out csv files as streams. Here's a really good CSV reader that will allow you to read and work on one record at a time:

> A Fast CSV Reader
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

You want to open the source for reading and the destination for writing at the same time. As you read a line from the source, process it, and then write to the destination. You should never have more than a line or a few lines in memory. This will be far more efficient both in terms of memory usage and performance.

For higher performance you could use separate reading/writing threads and a producer/consumer queue, but that takes a lot more management to ensure the queue doesn't get saturated and depending on the situation and relative read/process/write performance, this more complex solution may not increase performance at all.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try and implement that pattern. How would you do if if the data source is coming from a SQL query. Would you read the data into chunks and then use the producer/consumer pattern do then write the data for every set of data parts you get?

Comment: @Paul use a `IDataReader` instead of a `DataTable` and you'll process it one row at a time. In general always use a data reader if at all possible and avoid data tables when not necessary (but don't avoid at all costs, just if it's simple enough to use a reader instead, or if you have a lot of data).